# Deleting a specific object inside nested arrays in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a mongoDB collection, named myCollection, and inside myCollection there are different documents with a structure like this:

```
{
    "id": 1234,
    "posts": [
       [
          {
             "id": "0.0",
             "name": "john",
             "message": "hello"
          },
          {
             "id": "0.1",
             "name": "jane",
             "message": "good morning"
          },
          {
             "id": "0.2",
             "name": "josh",
             "message": "good evening"
          }
       ],
       [
          {
             "id": "1.0",
             "name": "mark",
             "message": "good lunch"
          }
       ],
       [
          {
             "id": "2.0",
             "name": "john",
             "message": "bye bye"
          },
          {
             "id": "2.1",
             "name": "mark",
             "message": "hi"
          }
       ]
    ]
}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can delete a specific object inside the nested "posts" arrays?
For example, launching a query around this specific object of the document with id=1234:

```
      {
         "id": "0.1",
         "name": "jane",
         "message": "good morning"
      }
```

I would like the structure of the object with id=1234 to become this:

```
{
    "id": 1234,
    "posts": [
       [
          {
             "id": "0.0",
             "name": "john",
             "message": "hello"
          },
          {
             "id": "0.2",
             "name": "josh",
             "message": "good evening"
          }
       ],
       [
          {
             "id": "1.0",
             "name": "mark",
             "message": "good lunch"
          }
       ],
       [
          {
             "id": "2.0",
             "name": "john",
             "message": "bye bye"
          },
          {
             "id": "2.1",
             "name": "mark",
             "message": "hi"
          }
       ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below query

```
db.getCollection("test1").update(
  {
    "id": 1234,
    "posts": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "id": "0.1",
          "name": "jane",
          "message": "good morning"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$pull": {
      "posts.$": {
        "id": "0.1",
        "name": "jane",
        "message": "good morning"
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help! It works correctly!
I have just updated my original post with a second question that I don't know how to resolve. Can you help me also with this new problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull the document and fire update.

```
  db.myCollection.update(
  { id : 1234 },
  {
    $pull : {"posts.0" :   {
         "id": "0.1",
         "name": "jane",
         "message": "good morning"
      }
   } 
 })
```